# New Ruby 1.9 hash syntax

Tags: ruby, jruby, syntax-error

```
new_hash = {:simon => "Talek", :lorem => "Ipsum"}
```

can be replaced by

```
new_hash = {simon: "Talek", lorem: "Ipsum"}
```

Is there also a shorter way of writing

```
:on => :collection
```

Applying the same logic raises an error:

```
on: :collection
```

Update to provide more info:

In my routes.rb:

```
get 'detail', { on: :member }
```

doesn't work. Neither does

```
get 'detail',  on: :member
```

Error:

```
Exiting
SyntaxError: C:/Workspace/OE_11/CyberTrack_Rails3/config/routes.rb:23: 
  syntax error, unexpected ':'

      get 'detail', { on: :member }
```

or

```
Exiting
SyntaxError: C:/Workspace/OE_11/CyberTrack_Rails3/config/routes.rb:23: 
  syntax error, unexpected ':'

      get 'detail', on: :member
```

Comment: Please provide a full example of what you are trying to do. `:on => :collection` by itself has no meaning.

Comment: Errr…that works fine? `{on: :collection}` produces `{:on=>:collection}` for me in IRB (Ruby 1.9.2).

Comment: How are you trying to use it? It works fine for me as `h = {on: :collection}`

Comment: In my routes.rb: get 'detail', { on: :member } gives me an error.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail than "raises an error"? Which error? Where?

Comment: Totally unrelated question: is that an OpenEdge 11 path I detect?  Are you running Rails against an OpenEdge database?  If so, care to share some details on the ORM layer?  I'm writing a DataMapper adapter for it right now so I'm just a bit curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
def get(*args) p *args end

get 'detail', on: :member
# "detail"
# { :on => :member }

RUBY_ENGINE
# => jruby
JRUBY_VERSION
# => 1.6.6
```

EDIT: Now that you provided the error message, it looks like you are not running Ruby 1.9. The new hash syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9, it doesn't work in older versions. You need to make sure that you are running Ruby 1.9, either by verifying that you are running the right Ruby implementation (e.g. YARV supports 1.9, MRI doesn't) or, if you are running a Ruby implementation that supports multiple language versions (e.g. JRuby) that you are passing the correct command line flags (e.g. `jruby --1.9`).

Comment: Strange. I am using JRuby 1.6.6... maybe it doesn't support the new Ruby syntax?

Comment: Are you running JRuby in 1.9-mode?

Comment: JRuby 1.6.6 supports both 1.8.7p357 and 1.9.2p312, so it should work. (In fact, I *know* that it works, and it has worked for several years at least, since that's how long I've already been using it.) But obviously only if you run it in 1.9 mode.

Comment: How do you run it in 1.9 mode instead of 1.8 mode?

Comment: @LievenCardoen: `jruby --1.9`

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need to use 1.9 to get this syntax to work.  Setting the environment variable `JRUBY_OPTS` to `--1.9` will ensure you are using the right ruby version.

Answer (score -1):

Bare `action: 'edit'` and `:action => 'edit'` are both syntax errors. You can only pass hashes without brackets **as the last argument** of  a method. In all other situations, use `{action: 'edit'}`.

For this to work, you have to be running ruby 1.9+: `get 'detail', { on: :member }`

Comment: You can only pass hashes without brackets to methods **if** the hash is the last parameter in the set. Anyway, OP got it right.